# SELECT and INSERT if true in the same query

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to first SELECT from DB and then if something is true INSERT into db within the same query?

Here is how I do right now:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$prefix."_active_users WHERE userid = $playerid AND DATE(timestamp) = '$sel_tag'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

if(!$row){
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$prefix."_active_users (userid,timestamp) VALUES ($playerid,'$now')");
}
```

Hoping for help and thanks ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I read the question, you want to INSERT if **no row** exists.

So, in one query...

```
mysql_query("

   INSERT INTO ".$prefix."_active_users (userid,timestamp)
   SELECT $playerid, '$now'
   FROM dual
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ".$prefix."_active_users
             WHERE userid = $playerid AND   DATE(timestamp) = '$sel_tag')
    ");
```

This is different to the other answers then `INSERT.. SELECT`

Comment: @ypercube: ah yes, I changed to a dummy select. maybe dual isn't needed because I assume MySQL here

Comment: I think it needs it (because of the WHERE) but too lazy to test.

Comment: @ypercube: don't have MySQL to test, but SQL Server is OK with this.

Comment: Well actually. When using "FROM dual" I can never get an duplacate insert for the specific user. That is not what I try to accomplish. I don't want a duplicate record for the user if the timestamp is the current day.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into YourTable
(col1, col2, ...) 
select col1, col2, ... 
where not exists
    (
    select *
    from YourTabe
    where col1 = 42
    )
```